# Firebase.on() vs GET Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angularjs-scope, firebase

I'm following along a tutorial to create a mail client app for angular, and I'm deviating a little from the sinatra suggestion to implement a firebase backend. The HTML uses an `ng-repeat` angular directive to list the emails in `$scope.email` of the controller. When I use the `$http` method with a get request (as the tutorial I'm following does), `$scope.email` gets updated when the get request returns and everything seems to work fine. However, when I instead try and use the `fb.on()` method, my view doesn't get updated. I know that `fb.on` is asynchronous, and it does seem to update the `$scope.email` variable, but somehow the directive does not get updated.

The following works:

```
app.controller('MailListingController',function($scope, $http){
    $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:'https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/email.json'
}).success(function(data,status,headers){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.email=data;
        console.log($scope.email);

}).error(function(data,status,headers){
    console.log('error');
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
app.controller('MailListingController',function($scope, $http){
    fb = new Firebase("https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/email");
    fb.on("value",function(snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        $scope.email=snapshot.val();
        console.log($scope.email);
        //console shows $scope.email was successfully set

},  function(errorObject){
    console.log("the read failed: "+errorObject.code);
});
```

I know that Firebase has an Angularfire tutorial and it probably does this differently, but I don't understand what's wrong with the second approach. It seems like any issues of asynchronicity or scoping should apply equally to either methods, so I'm confused. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: what causes the new firebase object to emit a _value_ event?

Comment: According to the doc, it's triggered once initially and then any time the contents of the data changes. In the official firebase tutorial, they use it to get the data initially and then it keeps track of all the changes.

Comment: Read this section of the angularfire documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/beyond-angularfire.html , specifically the how and why of $timeout.